# CSS Pseudo-element not working in React while using relative and absolute positioning

Tags: css, reactjs

```
.call-icon{
    height: 10vw;
    width: 10vw;
    box-shadow: white 0 0 5px;
    position: relative;
    
    
}
.call-icon:before{
    content: " ";
    top:0;
    position: absolute;
    height: 12vw;
    width: 12vw;
  
    background-color: red;
    filter: blur(50px);
    
    z-index: -2;
}
```

The pseudo element is not displaying while using abosolute positioning. I tried without positionings it dosent work either.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please delete `z-index: -2` or set it `z-index: 0` or if you going to use `z-index` for another thing u can change your **body** element background-color property to `background-color: transparent`

```css
.container{
  background-color: transparent;
  height: 100vh;
  display:grid;
  place-content: center;
}

.call-icon{
  height: 10vw;
  width: 10vw;
  box-shadow: white 0 0 5px;
  position: relative;
}

.call-icon:before{
  content: " ";
  top:0;
  position: absolute;
  height: 12vw;
  width: 12vw;

  background-color: red;
  filter: blur(50px);
  z-index: -2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="call-icon"></div>
</div>
```